# Problem Customize <input type="search" ...> Jquery Mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I want to show the message "search" in the filed with an id of "search" and have it disappear when the user clicks. Here is my code. It doesn't work.

```
 <script>
 $('#acceuil').live('pagecreate',function(event){
 $('#search').blur(function(){
    if ($('#search').val()=='')
    $('#search').val("search");
});

$('#search').focus(function(){
    if (('#search').val()=='search')
    $('#search').val("");
});
});
</script>



<div data-role="page" id ="acceuil" >
<div data-role="header" data-theme="a" ><h3>TEST</h3></div>
<div data-role="content">
   <div data-role="container" >
    <img src="images/olampromo.gif">
</div>
<div data-role="container">
    <label for="search">Cherchez votre coupon :</label>
    <input type="search" id="search" value="search">        
</div>

</div>
<div data-role="footer" data-theme="a" ><h3>footer</h3></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed a `$` in your JS. Try changing the line:

```
if (('#search').val()=='search')
```

to:

```
if ($('#search').val()=='search')
```

You could further improve it by making use of `this`. `this` will refer to the object that the event was triggered on (i.e. the search element). So, try instead:

```
if ($(this).val()=='search')
```

The same logic applies to both the blur and focus handlers.

Here's a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Spycho/u7kaG/) demonstrating the solution.

Answer (score 8):

Why not use the HTML5 native placeholder attribute? no JS needed.

```
<input type="text" id="searchBox" placeholder="search..." />
```

Live Example:

- http://jsfiddle.net/phillpafford/TQYvT/1/

Comment: That's a good point. Also, the OP is already using the HTML5 `type="search"`, so adding in more HTML5 is potentially acceptable? It wouldn't work for older browsers though, whereas `type="search"` is supposed to gracefully degrade to `type="text"`.

Comment: if he wants legacy support I would use a hybrid method of both techniques. Good point though for older browsers

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
        $("#search").focus(function(srcc) {
        var p_val = "Search";
        if ($(this).val() == p_val) {
            $(this).val("");
        }
    });

    $("#search").blur(function() {
        var p_val = "Search";
        if ($(this).val() == "") {
            $(this).val(p_val);
        }
    });

    $("#search").blur();
```