# jQuery blur not working on refreshing a page in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, focus

We have a textbox which contains a watermark in it with a normal focus and blur events in jQuery. In IE browsers alone, the problem is when we click on the textbox, the watermark disappears and then if we refresh the page. The cursor is focussed on the end of the watermark and the text we type gets appended to the watermark. I just want to cursor to disappear from the textbox on refreshing the page.

Comment: check my answer in this post few mins ago http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7040352/problem-customize-input-type-search-jquery-mobile/7040502#7040502

Comment: That seems fine.  Can you show what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

You can user [`.blur()`](http://api.jquery.com/blur/):

```
$( document ).ready( function() {
    $( '#id_of_textfield' ).blur();
} );
```

If this doesn't work on IE, you could try forcing a focus on some other element on the page (because two elements can't have the focus at the same time this would remove it from the textfield). Based on a comment in the API, another thing to try is to give the field focus first before blurring: `$( '#id_of_textfield' ).focus().blur();`

Comment: hi. thanks for the code. But that one doesnt seem to be working in IE browsers. In IE still the cursor is positioned inside the textbox. :(

Comment: Hi, i tried both the ways. this one seems to be so tricky. If u give focus to any other element, the focus gets shifted to the new element. but the bloody cursor still remains in the textbox(oly in IE). if u give alert in ur function, the thing is working fine in IE also....

Comment: thats ok Juhana. thanks a lot for the ideas..i m trying to find out. will post it if something works for me :)